# Python Only Include Numeric Columns in Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a linear regression program that works with any data set and I want this function to filter out the non-numeric columns and as a result, create a data frame with only numeric columns. In the code, you can see that this function takes a data frame (this is a data frame already uploaded in another function) and then creates a new data frame that appends the columns that are numeric. The issue is that when I run it, all columns remain (aka the non-numeric columns remain). Could someone try to tell me what I am missing?

```
def x_y_arrays(dataframe):
    num_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    for column in dataframe.columns:
        if is_numeric_dtype(dataframe[column]):
            num_dataframe['column'] = column
```

Comment: [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)?

Comment: @Ch3steR I will try that tysm